# Best way to save and use config settings in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, constants

I'm new to AngularJS and just building an app to learn it. My app calls a REST API and right now I have the hostname hard coded in the app.  I want to make this in app setting (and maybe later have somewhere to configure it). I thought I'd start with a constant. Should it go in my app.js like this? If so, I'm not sure of the syntax for adding it to the .config settings with $routeProvider there too

```
 (function () {

        // Define module and add dependencies inside []
        var app = angular.module("haClient", ["ngRoute"]);

        app.constant('hostname', 'http://192.192.192.192:8176');

        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                // Register routes
                // Main route
                .when("/main", {
                    templateUrl: "main.html",
                    controller: "MainController"//,
                    //activeTab: 'home'
                })
                // Device List 
                .when("/devices", {
                    templateUrl: "devicelist.html",
                    controller: "DeviceListController"
                })
                // Device details (param is device name)
                .when("/device/:devicename", {
                    templateUrl: "device.html",
                    controller: "DeviceController"
                })
                // Invalid URL's get sent back to main route
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/main" });
        }); // End App Config

    }());
```

This is the module that needs to use it (called from controllers):

```
(function () {

    var deviceCtrl = function ($http) {
        var getDevices = function () {
            return $http.get("http://192.192.192.192:8176/devices.json/")
                          .then(function (response) {
                              return response.data;
                          });
        };

        // get details and return a promise
        var getDeviceDetails = function (deviceName) {
            return $http.get("http://192.192.192.192:8176/devices/" + deviceName + ".json/")
                          .then(function (response) {
                              return response.data;
                          });
        };


        // Public API
        return {
            getDeviceDetails: getDeviceDetails,
            getDevices: getDevices
    };
    };

    var module = angular.module("haClient");

}());
```

Can someone enlighten em on the best way to set it and get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I currently do this by using templates to build the root `.html` file in the backend. Eg, using doT templates in node.js, I put this below my other js includes:

```
<!-- load any templated constants -->
<script>
    angular.module('mymod').constant('globals', {
        api: '{{=it.api}}'
    });
</script>
```

This way my backend can work out the logic of where the client needs to point to. In order to use the value in another service or controller, you simply inject the constant by name:

```
angular.module('somemod', []).factory('myservice', ['globals', function(globals){
    // use globals.api or what ever you set here for example
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best place to do configuration is in a Provider and inside your config block.

Providers expose an API that allows you to configure your service before it's injected into your controllers and directives.

Suppose you have a service called myService that you want injected into your controller function like this:

```
 app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, myService) { ...});
```

And myService is responsible for retrieving data through web API calls.  Let's further assume that you would like to configure your service with the root URL htt://servername/, since all calls will share the same host name.

You can define your myServiceProvider like this:

```
 app.provider('myService', function(){
        var webapiurl;
        this.setWebServiceUrl = function (url) {
                webapiurl = url;
        }

        // the injector will call the $get function to create the singleton service that will be injected
        this.$get = function( /*injectables*/) {
             return {
                      getData: function() {... Use webapiurl ...}
              }
        }
   });
```

Then in your config function, configure your provider:

```
  app.config(function(myServiceProvider){
          myServiceProvider.setWebServiceUrl('htt://servername');

  });
```

Finally you can inject the service anywhere it can be injected:

```
 app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, myService) {
         $scope.data = myService.getData();
  });
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. I've tried to apply it, but I'm still totally lost what goes where. Where you said "You can define your myServiceProvider like this" is that a new file (keeping stuff separate). What is */Injectables*/. What is "Use webapiurl"

Comment: I suggest that you put everything in the same script file until you get the hang of things.  Angular uses dependency injection to inject services into your controller function (and directives too). Dependency Injection is used in a lot of places in Angular.  You should do a search for "how does dependency injection work in Angular" and you will find a few good tutorials.

Comment: In your provider, once you've configured 'webapiurl' variable, you can use it however way you want. It was just an example and used for demonstration purposes. You use whatever custom variables you want.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the supplied answers to work (no reason to think they wouldn't). here's what I did.

My main app.js (constants section)

```
(function () {

    // Define module and add dependencies inside []
    var app = angular.module("haClient", ["ngRoute"]);

    //constants
    app.constant('mySettings', {
        baseURL:      'http://192.192.192.192:8176',
        otherSetting: 'XYZ'
    });


    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            // Register routes
            // Main route
            .when("/main", {
                templateUrl: "main.html",
                controller: "MainController"//,
                //activeTab: 'home'
            })
            // Device List 
            .when("/devices", {
                templateUrl: "devicelist.html",
                controller: "DeviceListController"
            })
            // Device details (param is device name)
            .when("/device/:devicename", {
                templateUrl: "device.html",
                controller: "DeviceController"
            })
            // Invalid URL's get sent back to main route
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/main" });

    }); // End App Config

}());
```

In my service (added mySettings as a dependency and then just used mySettings.baseURL):

```
(function () {

     var deviceCtrl = function ($http, $log, mySettings) {

         $log.info("DeviceCtrl - baseURL: " + mySettings.baseURL);

         // get device list and return a promise
         var getDevices = function () {
            return $http.get(mySettings.baseURL + "/devices.json")
                          .then(function (response) {
                              return response.data;
                          });
        };

        // get details and return a promise
        var getDeviceDetails = function (deviceName) {
            $log.info("DeviceCtrl - Getting device info for " + deviceName);
            return $http.get(mySettings.baseURL + "/devices/" + deviceName + ".json")
                          .then(function (response) {
                              return response.data;
                          });
        };


        // Public API
        return {
            getDeviceDetails: getDeviceDetails,
            getDevices: getDevices
    };
    };

     var module = angular.module("haClient");
     module.factory("deviceCtrl", deviceCtrl);

}());
```

I'm certainly no expert (as is clear from not being able to get supplied answers working), and I'm not sure (yet) if there are any drawbacks to this method. It allowed me to get on with my project and learn more of Angular, so I went with it.

Regards

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I have used another module and injected it into app module like this

1. Create constant.js and include that in your index.html & add following code inside that

   `angular.module('constantsModule', []).constant('BASEURL', 'http://google.com');`
2. Inside app.js, inject 'constantsModule' so that all constants inside it will be available for 'haClient'

   `angular.module('haClient', [
           'constantsModule'
       ])
       .config(function ($routeProvider) {
           .when('/', {
               templateUrl: 'views/landing.html',
               controller: 'landingCtrl'
           })
   });`
3. Inside landingCtrl, since its in scope of 'haClient', we can inject BASEURL constant from 'constantsModule'

   `angular.module('haClient').controller('landingCtrl', function ($scope, BASEURL) {
       // just to show, how to access it inside controller
       $scope.baseurl = BASEURL;
   });`